# App crash on WebKitLegacy framework in iOS 12.2

Tags: swift, crash, webkit

After updating an iOS version to 12.2, our app is getting crashed on WebKitLegacy framework. Also, we're unable to re-produce it. PFB crash report from HockeyApp,

[image]

Let me know, if you guys have come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen the same issue on iPads running iOS 12.2, looks like an Apple bug.